# How to load "Windows" to Chakra namespace on ReactNative Windows?

Tags: windows, react-native

I'd like to get access to Windows namespace and specific tools like "Windows.Storage" from js within my ReactNative Windows project.
As I understood the "Windows" context isn't passed to js bundle (which is strange) but there should probably be the way to change this.

In theory I should be able to do smth like this `JsProjectWinRTNamespace(L"Windows.Storage");` from within the project.
In case of ReactNative it should probably be `Native.JsProjectWinRTNamespace(L"Windows.Storage");`. 
But I can't understand where this line should be placed.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems I've found this. 
You should be able to edit `InitializeChakra()` function in `react-native-windows/ReactWindows/ReactNative/Chakra/Executor/ChakraJavaScriptExecutor.cs` by adding `Native.JsProjectWinRTNamespace(L"Windows.Storage");` line to it, so it'll look like the following:

```
    private void InitializeChakra()
    {
        JavaScriptContext.Current = _runtime.CreateContext();

        var consolePropertyId = default(JavaScriptPropertyId);
        Native.ThrowIfError(
            Native.JsGetPropertyIdFromName("console", out consolePropertyId));

        Native.JsProjectWinRTNamespace(L"Windows.Storage");

        var consoleObject = JavaScriptValue.CreateObject();
        EnsureGlobalObject().SetProperty(consolePropertyId, consoleObject, true);

        _consoleInfo = ConsoleInfo;
        _consoleLog = ConsoleLog;
        _consoleWarn = ConsoleWarn;
        _consoleError = ConsoleError;

        DefineHostCallback(consoleObject, "info", _consoleInfo);
        DefineHostCallback(consoleObject, "log", _consoleLog);
        DefineHostCallback(consoleObject, "warn", _consoleWarn);
        DefineHostCallback(consoleObject, "error", _consoleError);

        Debug.WriteLine("Chakra initialization successful.");
    }
```

Now, you'll be able to use Windows API directly from the ReactNative js code e.g:

`var path = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder.path;`.

!!! But be careful as this namespace will be available only in Chakra runtime, so when debugging app with Chrome - there will constantly be `'Windows is undefined'` errors.